# ClassNotFoundException Error in my server

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, classnotfoundexception

I wrote this code in netbeans and my local server (Netbeans) can run successfully

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%
                   try{
                Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); //Load the driver
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname", "dbuser", "password"); //Connect
                    ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT `name` FROM `people`");
                    while (rs.next() == true){
                        out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception err){
                        out.println(err.toString());
                }


        %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to run in my server I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

Mysql jar file is in WEB-INF/lib folder and it works fine in local server.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

rather than

```
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

Comment: doesn't work. I am getting this "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: Your JAR file may be corrupt. re-download the file and place it in `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

If you can access youj server,place the jar file in the lib dir in your server.Though this is not a good way to do about things,you could resolve your issue.I think here must be some prblmens in the jar

Comment: It is already in lib folder and how jar works fine in local if something is wrong with jar?

Comment: is the jar currenly place in WEB-INF/lib folder right?I am asking you ro place it in the servers lib folder

Comment: For ex: if you are using tomcat ,place it under tomcat/lib manually..in your case the server is unable to find the jar ,which is currently placed in the WEB-INF/lib